# How to check two values in codeigniter in_array function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following array values in $taxIdarr array

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 )
```

How can i check the value 1,2 in in_array I am using the following code

```
if(in_array("1,2",$taxIdarr))
{
   echo "test";
}
```

But not working.Please help me

Comment: please clarify your question, do you want to check that both 1 and 2 are contained?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `array_intersect` function. Please check following ans:
Your array is:

`$taxIdarr = array('1', '2', '1');`

now create one haystack array for which you want to check if it is in array or not. i.e. 1 & 2

`$haystack = array('1', '2');`

Now check using `array_intersect`

```
if(count(array_intersect($haystack, $taxIdarr)) > 0){
     // at least one of $taxIdarr is in $haystack
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check if both 1 and 2 are present in the array. In that case, try this:

```
if (in_array("1",$taxIdarr) && in_array("1",$taxIdarr)) {
  echo "test";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am changing my code like this its working fine.

```
if(in_array("1",$taxIdarr) && !in_array("2",$taxIdarr))
 {
    echo "test1";
 }

 if(in_array("2",$taxIdarr) && !in_array("1",$taxIdarr))
 {
    echo "test2";
 }
  if(in_array("1",$taxIdarr) && in_array("2",$taxIdarr))
 {
    echo "test3";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array= Array ( "1","2","1","3" );
$target = array('1', '2');

if(count(array_intersect( array_unique($array), $target)) == count($target)){
echo "all of is in array";
}else{
echo "all of is not in array";
}
```